# Go: Server side logging for MaxHeaderBytes error 431 Request Header Fields Too Large

Tags: go

I created a Go server like this:

```
s := &http.Server{
    Addr:    ":8080",
    Handler: http.HandlerFunc(func(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        log.Println(r.Method, r.URL.Path)
    }),
    MaxHeaderBytes: 1,
}
s.ListenAndServe()
```

Then I sent a request with a large header to test the `MaxHeaderBytes` limit.

```
$ curl -H "X-Request-Id: $(head -c 4005 < /dev/zero | tr '\0' '\141')" http://localhost:8080/
431 Request Header Fields Too Large
```

For some reason `4005` triggers the limit, but `4004` does not trigger the limit even though I set `MaxHeaderBytes` to 1, but that's besides the point. (This issue is out of scope for this question. My question is about logging. Please don't address the limit behavior here.)

My question is: How can I learn about the 431 error on the server side?

When this error gets triggered, I don't see any logs on the server—not even from the log package's standard logger. Only the client gets the error. I had no idea I was hitting this error on the server side.

Is there anything I can do to surface this error?

Setting `Server.ErrorLog` doesn't log this case.

Answer (score 2):

I can see that the header read limit for `http.Server` is controlled by the below function

```
func (srv *Server) initialReadLimitSize() int64 {
    return int64(srv.maxHeaderBytes()) + 4096 // bufio slop
}
```

With the maxHeaderBytes() coming from

```
// DefaultMaxHeaderBytes is the maximum permitted size of the headers
// in an HTTP request.
// This can be overridden by setting Server.MaxHeaderBytes.
const DefaultMaxHeaderBytes = 1 << 20 // 1 MB

func (srv *Server) maxHeaderBytes() int {
    if srv.MaxHeaderBytes > 0 {
        return srv.MaxHeaderBytes
    }
    return DefaultMaxHeaderBytes
}
```

The default header size is thus `1 MB + 4096` bytes when MaxHeaderBytes is unspecified. In your case, it turns out to be `1 + 4096 = 4097 bytes`.

The catch here is that there is no way to reduce the actual header size to 1 as the `DefaultMaxHeaderBytes` (1MB) will be used if you provide 0 or a negative value. On top of that cURL appends other headers like
`Accept=*/*` and `User-Agent=curl/7.73.0` which would be contributing towards breaching the limit of 4097 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

You can make ur own logger for error logging, via field `ErrorLog` which is type of `*log.Logger` that guarantees that each log message is delivered to the destination io.Writer with a single Writer.Write() <- https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Server

But if you want to handle that in your code (specifically header), then i would handle that directly in ur own handler by myself.
Thats why you are setting up configuration that guarantees that will refuse connection above specific size of bytes.

Comment: Setting `Server.ErrorLog` does not log anything when the header limit is passed. That's what I'm trying to do, to log this case.

Comment: Also, implementing the behavior in the handler probably means that the entire header was already loaded into memory... defeating the purpose of limiting in the first place.